# What is the difference between number and Number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, instanceof, typeof

The output of:

```
var x = 5;
typeof (x) //will give number type as output
```

But for the below code it returns false:

```
var x = 5;
x instanceof Number; //will give false as output
```

Can anybody please explain the difference between number and Number. And how do I make the second one work?

Comment: To add to the above, for the second block since x is of type number it should output true which isn't the case?

Comment: What do you mean how to make it "work"? What is your goal? If you want to check if a variable is a number, you'll do `typeof x === 'number'` like you do in the first code.

Comment: Have a read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof for more information, should clear it up

Comment: what is your objective of doing that second one work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof(x)` always returns a string that represents type x belongs to.

`instanceOf` operator uses `prototype` property to identify whether an instance belongs to a class or not.

`x instanceof Number;` in your case returns `false` because `x` is a **primitive** and would never return `true`. If you do want it return true, you can "wrap" your primitive into a `Number` class like so:

`new Number(x) instanceof Number; //will give TRUE as output`

Answer (score 1):

> how do I make the second one work?

[`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator checks if a given variable is an object of a class. Per definition by MDN,

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether the `prototype` property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.

To make it work, you need to instantiate the variable using `Number` class' (or any of its descendent class') constructor:

```
var x = new Number(5);
x instanceof Number // true
```